# How to conditionally WHERE populated foreign keys with OneToMany Entity?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, criteria

I am assuming a setup as described in: https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-mapping-using-annotations/

[image: one to many relation]

**Employee:**

```
@JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
private Set<AccountEntity> accounts;
```

**Account:**

```
@ManyToOne
private EmployeeEntity employee;
```

Using JPA/Hibernate, how can I fetch results using a `WHERE` condition that applies to Account. In other words, query something like `Select all employees with accounts with sales > 0` or similar.

Comment: Where is the sales column in the account table?

Comment: @Abhijeet the `sales` column would be a number value (INT, ...) in the accounts table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming sales column as INT in account table.

you can write a query like following:

```
TypedQuery<Employee> query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Employee e JOIN Account a ON e.id = a.accounts.employee_id WHERE a.sales > :sales", Employee.class);
query.setParameter("sales", salesInput);
List<Employee> items = query.getResultList();
```

I would recommend you to go through this tutorial to learn about CRUD operations in Hibernate Associations
https://www.dineshonjava.com/spring-crud-example-using-many-to-one/

Comment: When generating the query from a self-written string-query, is it still possible to use methods like `.setFirstResult` and `.setMaxResults`?

Comment: yes. Its possible. `query.setFirstResult(0);
query.setMaxResults(5);` like this and then call `getResultList` method

Comment: @janniks I would recommend you to go through this https://www.dineshonjava.com/spring-crud-example-using-many-to-one/ tutorial

Comment: Is the same functionality also possible using criteria builder instead of `TypedQuery` ?

Comment: Yes its possible. You can use criteria as well@janniks